# Compare number of calls to domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: google-analytics

We are interested in the number of people that reach our website by calling http://domain.com and those calling http://www.domain.com

Is there a way to obtain this number using Google Analytics (which is present and active on both)?

Comment: That should be part of the hostname field, so do a custom report with hostname as dimension and visits as metric (also quite possibly OT since the question is not about code).

Comment: When I figured out how to file a custom report (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) I was able to obtain my values by exactly the process you gave. Thx